# Symfony, use variable from a bundle different of the one which called the twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

So my problem is that I use a CommonBundle to manage every common part of my project, and a bundle for each page. So I call the "ABundle" and the "a.html.twig", extend with the "common.html.twig" and then I would like to use a common form from CommonBundle. The problem is that because it's not the same bundle, I can't access the variable obviously... So how should I do?

Ask me if you need any other information.

EDIT:

```
<?php

namespace ST\CommonBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use ST\ConnexionBundle\Entity\Profil;
use ST\ConnexionBundle\Controller\ConnexiondController;
use ST\ConnexionBundle\Resources\Util\InscriptionHelper;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
protected $_inscriptionHelper;

/**
 * Set your services here (we need to override this method to initialize our services into class properties)
 *
 * @param \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container
 */
public function setContainer(\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container = null)
{
    parent::setContainer($container);
    $this->_inscriptionHelper = $this->get('st_inscription_service');
} 

public function commonAction($pageName)
{
    $inscriptionForm = $this->_inscriptionHelper->getInscriptionForm();
    if ($response = $this->_inscriptionHelper->doInscription($inscriptionForm))
    {
        return $response;
    }

    return $this->render('STCommonBundle:Default:common.html.twig',
        array('inscriptionform' => $inscriptionForm->createView()));
    }
}
```

common.html.twig

```
{% block connexion %}

    {{ form(inscriptionform) }}

{% endblock %}

</header>
```

accueil.html.twig

```
{% extends "STCommonBundle:Default:common.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}

    /*body*/

{% endblock %}
```

I have clean the code to keep the essential, if you need more of it please tell me which part so I can keep it "clear".

Thank you for your help.

Comment: please provide the controller code and twig templates

Comment: What variable you are talking about ??

Comment: I've done an edit. For the variable I'm aiming to use a form but I would like to use any kind of variables, always if it could work that way. ^^

Comment: the controller action that renders accueil.html.twig should also do something with a form. The ABundle controller should extend the CommonBundle or should handle the form on its own

Comment: That actually my problem, I have many pages so I would like to not do that. Is there any way to keep a common code?

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand the question but your accueil.html.twig could embed your commonAction controller: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers.